# Auto Vacuum with Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to limit the size of a database in flask using Flask_SQLAlchemy.  I want to start removing the oldest rows when the file size nears some limit set.  I figured out how to remove rows from the beginning of the database, but the file size doesn't shrink because vacuuming isn't on (I think).

Is there a way to enable that or a better way to manage filesizes for a database in SQLAlchemy?  I'm new to databases so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a way to do this using SQLite3 in python, I'll add it here in case anyone finds this page and needs help.  To vacuum after deleting, I just ran these three commands.

```
self.con = sqlite3.connect(databasename) # Open the database in sqlite
self.con.execute("VACUUM") # Execute the vacuum command
self.con.close() # Close the database
```

If anyone has a better way to do this which is native to SQLAlchemy please let us know!

Answer (score 3):

I use my `db = SQLAlchemy()` object
and call

```
with db.engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute("VACUUM")
```